# How to deploy Sieve scripts on Apache James

Tags: email, james, sieve-language

I have spent two days trying to find a clear instructions on how Sieve scripts are deployed on Apache James. I found some hints that scripts go into "../apps/james/var/" with name such as "username@host.sieve", but doing just that did not work for me. I am missing something.

Any help is greatly appreciated:

1. Where do Sieve scripts go in James folder hierarchy?
2. Are there any
   necessary configuration file changes?
3. Is any coding required?
4. Are there difference in deployment of scripts under James version
   2.2, 2.3 and latest (3.0)?